# Why is Itô integration not a "pathwise solution theory" to SDEs, but rough path theory is?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am studying the rough path theory of Lyons and am struggling to understand a heuristic claim made in several books and articles.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t, P, B_t)$ be a filtered probability space on which a standard Brownian motion $B_t$ is defined. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function (say, Lipschitz). Suppose $X_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process which solves the SDE $dX_t = f(X_t)dB_t$, that is, such that $X_t$ satisfies
$$
X_t - X_0 = \int_0^tf(X_s)dB_s\quad\text{a.s.},
$$
where the the integral is in the sense of Itô. The Itô integral can then be obtained as the limit in $L^2$ of the Riemann-Stieltjes sum:
$$
\sum_{0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=t}f(X_{t_i})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})\xrightarrow{\sup_i|t_i-t_{i+1}|\to 0}_{L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)}\int_0^tf(X_s)dB_s.
$$
Many authors claim that rough path theory constitutes a "pathwise SDE solution theory": given a realization $B_t(\omega)$ of the driving Brownian motion, one can solve the corresponding "rough differential equation" driven by the corresponding realization of the Brownian rough path. In particular, the analogous statement is claimed to **not** hold for the Itô integral, because the above limit is only in $L^2$ (indeed, the above limit cannot be almost sure because Brownian motion has unbounded variation on any compact interval). On the other hand, a routine application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma shows the existence of a sequence of partitions along which the above limit **is** almost sure. My question is: **in what sense does the realization of the Itô integrals $\int_0^tf(X_s)dB_s$ as an a.s. limit of Riemann-Stieljtes sums fail to constitute a "pathwise solution theory?"** What defect of this "pathwise" construction does rough path theory mitigate?

Comment: You are correct. There is *always* a sequence of partitions along with the limit ***is*** almost sure. Reading [Motivation of Rough Path Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path#Motivation) in particular when they say, *"This continuity property and the deterministic nature of solutions makes it possible to simplify and strengthen many results in Stochastic Analysis, such as the Freidlin-Wentzell's Large Deviation theory as well as results about stochastic flows."* it strikes me as an interesting tool for some special applications. In 30 years of working with Ito calculus the orthodox

Comment: ... definition of the integral was always good enough for me. Having said that, and probably to answer your question: Ito is not a pathwise solution theory because in the orthodox approach we cannot do wihout $L^2$.

Comment: @KurtG. I’m afraid you haven’t answered my question at all. You say “we cannot do without $L^2$“—why not? In what sense and contexts do we need it?

Comment: If you dive into the standard definitions of the Ito integral you will notice what I said. There is no need to reproduce that here on MSE.

Comment: When you want to show that an SDE has a well-defined flow, a priori, you only know that for any initial condition there exists a solution almost surely i.e. you have a collection of uncountable many null sets (one for each initial condition) and it is not clear at all that their union is also a null set, i.e. that there is a single null set such that the solution is defined on its complement. If you work with rough paths, there is no such issue and the existence of stochastic flows is a trivial consequence of the theory

Comment: (of course, there is no free lunch; existence and uniqueness for rough ODEs requires more regularity on the vector fields)

Comment: For the "impossibility" of Path by path stochastic integration you can also have a look at the argument in Protter's book "Stochastic Integration" via Banach-Steinhaus theorem in the first chapter. You can have a look here also (doesn't cover rough path) :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653237/why-are-probabilities-needed-for-stochastic-differential-equations/1656572#1656572 or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190827/understand-better-stochastic-integral-through-a-s-convergence/3192318#3192318

Comment: @G.Chiusole thanks! I see what you mean: the rough solution map is defined for all Brownian trajectories outside of a fixed null set, no matter which initial data is chosen for the SDE. By the way,  something similar is true on the level of varying the vector fields, correct?

Comment: @TheBridge thanks for the references, they are helpful at first glance!

Comment: @Victor Yes, exactly. Also, the "pathwise" approach is not the only advantage of rough paths. It created a whole new philosophy of "higher order" information about paths (see e.g. section 3.4. in Friz-Hairer 2020 about Brownian motion in a magnetic field), ultimately leading to Hairer's theory of regularity structures and the reconstruction theorem, a vast generalization of the continuity result for the Ito-Lyons map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of an Itö-SDE $X_{t}=y+\int bdt+\int \sigma dB_{t}$ is defined outside a set of measure zero that depends on the whole equation i.e. $\Omega_{y,b,\sigma}$ with $P[\Omega_{y,b,\sigma}]=0$.

Considering another initial condition $y$ will create a new set of measure zero outside of which the solution is defined. Since the set of allowed initial conditions is not countable, it is a priori not clear whether

$$P[\bigcup_{y}\Omega_{y,b,\sigma}]=0,$$

i.e. that there exists a set of full measure on which an Itö-SDE can be solved for every initial condition $y$. For a pathwise solution theory such as rough paths, this is immediate. In rough paths, the solutions are built deterministically by postulating the existence of some iterated integrals.

see here too [On the pathwise uniqueness of solutions of SDEs(Stochastic Differential Equations)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145606/on-the-pathwise-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-sdesstochastic-differential-equation).